# Does a variable initialization in nested "for" loop inside broader "for" loop reinitialize the variable when broader "for" loop loops back around?

Tags: java

I'm trying to find out whether the initialization of a variable in a nested "for" loop (this loop is nested inside a broader "for" loop) will re-initialize the originally initialized variable when the program loops back to the nested "for" loop another time(after the first time)from the broader "for" loop.

There doesn't seem to be any internet stuff(including stack overflow) that addresses my problem specifically.

Example: Would "h" be reinitialized to whatever "k" is after the code runs 2 times? (I think k will be 1 at that point)

```
for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
{  
    for (int h = k; h >= 0; h--)
    {
        System.out.print(k);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: The answer is Yes.

Comment: Why don't you add a println() to see what the value of h is, execute that code, and see by yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding this part of the question:

> There doesn't seem to be any internet stuff...
>   that addresses my problem specifically.

The official Java tutorial actually contains a direct answer to your question:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

> The scope of this variable extends from its declaration to the end of
>   the block governed by the for statement...

Answer (score 0):

First loop (`for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++)`) will iterate 4 times. Every iteration will bring a new `h`. It means you will start with new `h` every time the loop iterate.